# Node.JS spawning Python process gives error 'JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None'

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I'm trying to spawn a python process (App.py) from a node.js file (index.js).

The script `index.js` spawns the python script `App.py`, and passes it an argument `params` (a json object). `App.py` then reads the `uParams` element `parameter1` and sends the value as a message back to index.js.

However when I run the index.js script I get the error, `JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None`.

I tried to replace `json.loads(sys.argv[1])` with `sys.argv[1]` but running it gives me the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Did I wrongly format the 'params' JSON object in `index.js`?

Could you please help me spot the problem?

Thanks in advance!

index.js:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

let params = {
  "type":"numbers",
  "lang":"js",
  "uParams":[{
    "parameter1":1,
    "parameter2":2,
    "parameter3":3
    }]  
}

const pythonProcess = spawn('python',['./App.py', params]);

pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data)=>{
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```

App.py:

```
import sys, json

params = json.loads(sys.argv[1])

print(params['uParams'][0]['parameter1'])
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stringify your JSON object with `JSON.stringify`.

```js
const pythonProcess = spawn('python',['./App.py', JSON.stringify(params)]);
```

Frankly I'm surprised `spawn` isn't complaining that it only accepts string arguments, but it must be calling `toString` on your object so you're just passing `[object Object]`.

```js
> ({foo:'bar'}).toString()
'[object Object]'
```